# choosing first scene with main storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

I am using the main view controller to make an app with different views and I am wondering how to choose which one goes first with xcode using the main storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can choose in "attributes inspector" in viewController voice "is initial view controller"

[image]